# AccessControlException when adding security provider on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jce

```
static {
    Security.addProvider(new iaik.security.provider.IAIK());
}
```

The above line of code is part of my GAE/Java project.
Unfortunately, it raises an exception upon execution:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.security.SecurityPermission putProviderProperty.IAIK)
```

Can't I use my desired JCE (IAIK JCE in this case) on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 0):

The GAE/J documentation features a "JRE Class White List" page, which lists the JRE classes allowed in GAE/J.

Your code may be trying to access a JRE class outside of this list.